# Sorting numbers high to low in C Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, structure

I would like to sort the indexes of the students that I added in the Main method according to the scores they get from high to low. This is the last form of the list that i want to create.

```
0,18061086,65
1,20060032,60
2,20060678,55
3,20060045,50
4,19061091,45
5,18060311,40
6,20060134,30
```

This is the code i wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student{
    int index;
    int studentnumber;
    int score;
    struct student* next;
};

typedef struct student Student;
void addStudent(Student **headOfList,int index,int studentnumber,int score);
void score(Student* headOfList);
int main(){
    Student* headOfList = NULL;
    addStudent(&headOfList,0,18060311,40);
    addStudent(&headOfList,1,20060045,50);
    addStudent(&headOfList,2,19061091,45);
    addStudent(&headOfList,3,20060134,30);
    addStudent(&headOfList,4,20060678,55);
    addStudent(&headOfList,5,18061086,65);
    addStudent(&headOfList,6,20060032,60);
    return 0;
}


void addStudent(Student **headOfList,int index,int studentnumber,int score){
    Student* currentStudent = (*headOfList);
    Student* newStudent = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    newStudent->index =index;
    newStudent->studentnumber = studentnumber;
    newStudent->score = score;
    newStudent->next = NULL;
    if(currentStudent == NULL){
        // if list is empty
        (*headOfList)= newStudent;
    }
    else{
        while(currentStudent->next != NULL){
            currentStudent = currentStudent->next;
        }   
        currentStudent -> next = newStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you track total number of students in head, then you could create an intermediate preallocated array of pointers to list elements. Using this list of pointers you could interface your own comparator to the stdlib qsort function. When the list of pointers is sorted according to your comparator, you can traverse your list, update next pointers one after each other starting from the second and finally update the next pointer in the head to the first pointer in the sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert the new student at the sorted location directly :

```
void display(Student* headOfList){ 
    Student* currentStudent= headOfList; 
    while(currentStudent!=NULL){ 
        printf("index no : %-3d student Number : %-6d student score : %-3d\n", 
        currentStudent->index,
        currentStudent->studentnumber,
        currentStudent->score); 
        currentStudent = currentStudent->next; 
    } 
} 

void addStudent(Student **headOfList,int index,int studentnumber,int score) {
    Student* currentStudent = (*headOfList);
    Student* newStudent = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    Student* prev = NULL;
    newStudent->index =index;
    newStudent->studentnumber = studentnumber;
    newStudent->score = score;
    newStudent->next = NULL;
    printf("====== Add new student :\n");
    if(currentStudent == NULL){
        // if list is empty
        (*headOfList)= newStudent;
    }
    else if (score >= (*headOfList)->score) {
        *headOfList = newStudent;
        newStudent->next = currentStudent;
    }
    else {
        while(currentStudent->next != NULL && currentStudent->next->score >= score) {
            currentStudent = currentStudent->next;
        }   
        //printf("%d %d \n", score, currentStudent->score);
        Student* next = currentStudent->next;
        currentStudent->next = newStudent;
        newStudent->next = next;
    }
    if (headOfList) {
        display(*headOfList);
    }
}

int main(){
    Student* headOfList = NULL;
    addStudent(&headOfList,0,18060311,40);
    addStudent(&headOfList,1,20060045,50);
    addStudent(&headOfList,2,19061091,45);
    addStudent(&headOfList,3,20060134,30);
    addStudent(&headOfList,4,20060678,55);
    addStudent(&headOfList,5,18061086,60);
    addStudent(&headOfList,6,20060032,60);
    
    printf("================ Final result :\n");
    display(headOfList);
    return 0;
}
/*
Program returned: 0
====== Add new student :
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
====== Add new student :
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
====== Add new student :
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 2   student Number : 19061091 student score : 45 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
====== Add new student :
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 2   student Number : 19061091 student score : 45 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
index no : 3   student Number : 20060134 student score : 30 
====== Add new student :
index no : 4   student Number : 20060678 student score : 55 
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 2   student Number : 19061091 student score : 45 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
index no : 3   student Number : 20060134 student score : 30 
====== Add new student :
index no : 5   student Number : 18061086 student score : 60 
index no : 4   student Number : 20060678 student score : 55 
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 2   student Number : 19061091 student score : 45 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
index no : 3   student Number : 20060134 student score : 30 
====== Add new student :
index no : 6   student Number : 20060032 student score : 60 
index no : 5   student Number : 18061086 student score : 60 
index no : 4   student Number : 20060678 student score : 55 
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 2   student Number : 19061091 student score : 45 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
index no : 3   student Number : 20060134 student score : 30 
================ Final result :
index no : 6   student Number : 20060032 student score : 60 
index no : 5   student Number : 18061086 student score : 60 
index no : 4   student Number : 20060678 student score : 55 
index no : 1   student Number : 20060045 student score : 50 
index no : 2   student Number : 19061091 student score : 45 
index no : 0   student Number : 18060311 student score : 40 
index no : 3   student Number : 20060134 student score : 30
*/
```

Comment: For students with equal scores, if the priority is the student with a lower student number, how should I change the code?

Comment: Replace < by <= in `currentStudent->next->score < score`

Comment: void display(Student* headOfList){
 Student* currentStudent= headOfList; 
 while(currentStudent!=NULL){
  printf("index no : %-3d  student Number : %-6d  student score : %-3d\n",
  currentStudent->index,currentStudent->studentnumber,currentStudent->score);
  currentStudent = currentStudent->next;
 }
}
i can't display the list. i think there is something wrong in "addstudent" method.

Comment: I inserted the `display` function in my post, however I don't see any problem : the list is correctly printed once for each new student and once at the very end of main (that one being the final list)

Comment: Thanks but i want to display scores high to low and also can i see the full code please. when i execute, it displays infinite times "index no : 3   student Number : 20060134 student score : 30" this.

Comment: Ok I didn't understand that, sorry : the codes work in reverse order now (I edited my post again). But for your problem of infinite loop I really cannot reproduce it. Do you try that with another list of students ? If yes post it, there could be a special case I didn't handle

Comment: 0,18060311,40
1,20060045,50
2,19061091,75
3,20060134,90
4,20060678,40  I solved the infinite loop problem but "lower student number priority" for equal scores does not work properly.

Comment: As I already told you, this question is relative to the comparison operator. In this case it is fixed by replacing `>` with `>=`    (I corrected my post).